# PHP CLI: How do I intercept terminal window/tab closure?

Tags: php, terminal, command-line-interface, pcntl

I use `pcntl_signal` function to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and exit at safe point from the application.

Can I do the same when user close window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the hangup signal.

SIGHUP

You can use:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

To find and overview of when each signal will be sent.

There no UI specific a specific "tab/window" closed signal and you would have to hook into X11 to accomplish anything like that (certainly not recommended especially in PHP) but SIGHUP is probably what you need.

There is a SIGCHLD but I don't know about anything that indicates that a parent is terminating which is what happens when you close the tab or window.

Comment: Window is closing instantly after confirmation: [terminal screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hw2EWaj.png), [code here](http://ideone.com/DI4e2R)